# Trading on WTO Rules

Tags: united-kingdom, economy, international-relations, wto, gdp

Many Countries are a member of some Regional Trading Organization, which facilitates trade within a particular continent, or have bilateral trade deals with other Countries. Are there any examples of Countries where at least half of the GDP is a result of trading purely on WTO rules?

Comment: Would there be any limits to any answer you'd want to see?  I imagine small island countries would make up the bulk of any list of such countries.

Comment: City-states and small islands are excluded. In the question I am referring to medium-to-large economies.

Comment: Is this question better suited for economics.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Half the GDP from trade is hard to find anyway, Dijbouti may be one place, which is mostly invisible trade, banking services etc

Comment: on a more constructive note... the OP's question sounds like it's meant as "nations for whom more than half of their trade GDP happens under WTO rules".

Comment: Yet it says something else "at least have of the GDP is a result of trading purely on WTO rules"

Comment: Not sure this question is really answerable or will get to what you are actually trying to learn. Unlike what the recent debate around Brexit might have you believe, “WTO rules” are not a set of trading regulations that are available as a ready-made set of rules for a country to opt in or out of. Things like tariff-rate quota needs to be hashed out by each member state and changes to them are subject to negotiation and litigation.

Comment: Importantly, WTO rules are very procedural in nature and cover regional trade agreements (EU, ASEAN, MERCOSUR…), preferential trade agreements and a bunch of exemptions (e.g. national security) so technically all WTO members operate under WTO rules (otherwise the WTO would not be able to function). The real question is how you might apply those rules, from a given starting point, and invoking “WTO rules” is not specific enough to describe a comparison point or a viable path for Britain.

Answer (score 5):

The question as posed is probably none.

Small highly trade dependent nations, such as oil rich Brunei, or Kuwait will be trading oil, and oil will provide a large amount of GDP. However WTO doesn't have much to do with the energy trade, there are other agreements that cover oil trade.

Dijbouti has few resources and much of their business is in invisibles (financial services etc) This makes up a large proportion of the GDP (on WTO terms) but this is not a "medium to large country".

The larger countries all have economies that are majority-domestic, Even highly integrated countries like the Netherlands still have more domestic production than production for export.

If, however, the question is "countries that do more than half of their trade on WTO terms", then look no further than China (PRC). Most of China's trade is with the USA, the EU, Japan, Korea, Australia.  And these countries are not part of the ASEAN China Free Trade Area.  In particular, the US and EU trade on WTO terms (with tariffs, etc...).

Comment: "In particular, the US and EU trade on WTO terms (with tariffs, etc...).". Yeah, I vividly remember the public discussion about TTIP in 2015/16.